# What is the `ActiveSupport::Cache::FileStore` key limit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, activesupport, memorycache

I am using Rails Model caching. When generating cache file, I am giving different formats to store data. Because of that, it takes 140-180 length file name, for example:

1000011_2000014_2000004_2000013_1000006_1000010_2000005_2000001_1000012_2000013_2000012_2000015_2000006_1000006_1000006_1000000_1000008_brand_list

May I know what the maximum length if for `ActiveSupport::Cache::FileStore` file name?

Answer (score 3):

I have found info in the [source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/cache/file_store.rb#L19):

> `FILENAME_MAX_SIZE = 228` # max filename size on file system is 255, minus room for timestamp and random characters appended by Tempfile (used by atomic write)